# To attach an image to an email on a html button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created a html button in my webpage, which can take screenshot of the screen and save it as an image. For that I used the following code.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin:0px 0px -10px 970px;  padding:2px 4px 1px 4px" onclick="genScreenshot()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>

<a id="test"></a>
<div id="box1"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                             
            function genScreenshot() {
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
  $('#box1').html("");
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
                                                                            navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
                                            {
            var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
  }
  else {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $('#test').attr('download','screenshot.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  }
  }
});
}  
</script>
```

Now, I want to attach this image to an `outlook` new mail after it gets downloaded (i.e., in one click it should download the screenshot and also attach it to the mail).
Is there a way to do it?
And if so, Please explain me clearly. I dont understand hard concepts. So, please explain it in *layman terms*.

Comment: What exactly is an "outlook email"?

Comment: Its **Microsoft outlook** a part of MS Office suite. Its a mail platform. I want to attach the image in a new mail.

Comment: I asked what an "outlook email" is, not what MS-Outlook is. I only know about email messages. That is a standard format and procedure. Company specific implementations should be irrelevant in that per definition of a standard. Although I agree that this usually is _not_ the case if MS tries to implement a standard...

Comment: We dont have to worry about the outlook application here, since outlook is my default mailing application. Please let me know how to attach the file in normal emails. That will do!

Comment: So your real question is simply "how to attach an image to an email message on a button click"?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry for framing the question wrongly. I will correct it now.

Comment: I am afraid there is no direct secure and reliable way to do that. Reason simply is that the client side logic (javascript) does _not_ have immediate access to the client side file system due to security reasons. There are some hacks that work on faulty browsers with incomplete privacy implementations. But as a general solution all I could think of is use a `mailto://` type link and include a full mime structured message body in that which contains the image as base64 encoded mime part. Sorry, that there is no easy solution for this, nothing like "layman terms".

Comment: `mailto` wont support images. I have tried it by encoding my image into base64. `mailto` only adds the encoded text and not the image.

Comment: That certainly won't work directly, since there is nothing that declares that base64 stream an image. I said you need to provide a full mime structure. That certainly _does_ work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the file, you can send it with a *mailto* link. Take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links

Probably best as a base64 encoded img element embedded in the email.

Comment: Sorry fistuks, this wont work. With `mailto` we cannot add images. It doesnt support images. There must be some other way to do it.